# Sync between sql server database and db2 database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, db2

I have a SQL Server Database and a DB2 Database, I need to sync a specific column in a specific table from the sql database to a specific column in a specific table from DB2 database periodically and automatically.

What is the best way to do that?

***SQL Database Info:***

```
Database Name: "SQLTest" 
Table Name:    "SQLTable"
Column Name:   "SqlValue"
```

***DB2 Database Info:***

```
Database Name: "Db2Test"
Table Name:    "DB2Table"
Column Name:   "Db2Value"
```

I know that i can do it programmatically with a windows service but i'm searching for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I would make it so

1. Create [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) and fill [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) from sql
2. Change [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) row states to [changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ch2aw0w6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
3. Create [Db2DataAdapter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2FDB2DataAdapterClass.html) and update database using existing [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know this already but i need something that would do it periodically and repeat it if the connection is down

Comment: @Sayed, I think you need to mention about that in question. what is the problem? put it in loop and repeat after some time if connection is down

Comment: I mentioned it to be periodically and automatically too so if the connection is down it will sync when the connection is back.

I know that i can do it programmatically with a windows service but i'm searching for a better solution